# JSTree bug with ngnix

Tags: webserver, jstree, nginx-reverse-proxy

A Laravel app is using the JSTree to display files.

If I get the tree under http://localhost:8000 I recive the correct tree.

We have a ngnix reverse Proxy setting to access the web site from behind a proxy.

But if I open the ngnix web site there are in some cases no data. The ajax response is correct, but JSTree doesn't render it.

Have anybody a idea?

Comment: I doubt this is a bug with jstree - it is a client side lib and is not related to how you receive the data.  
Provide a sample of the response (along with all headers) and any errors you may have in the console. Also it might help to check what `$("#jstree").jstree(true).last_error()` will report.

Answer (score 0):

First I tried out the jstree().last_error() function and it is a empty object.

Here are my header, I hope it helps:

```
Host: DOMAIN.de
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0)     Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://DOMAIN.de/explorer/show/443
Content-Length: 6
Cookie:      cartalyst_sentinel=eyJpdiI6I...iJ9; laravel_session=eyJp...J9
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The response:

```
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 06:37:12 GMT
Expires: -1
Host: DOMAIN.de
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie:     laravel_session=eyJpdi......3D; expires=Tue, 12-Apr-2016 08:37:35 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.19
```

The PHP header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

The problem is, with ngnix the response has another Content-Type. ngnix put "application/json" to "text/html".

Are there any options to modify this?